# .vob to h.264 MP4 Files - Worth The Effort?

Tags: video-conversion, h.264, vob

When I was doing the converting to digital format a while back I chose .VOB due to no quality loss. However recently I have been informed of this h.264 compression method.

Time is not an issue here, I don't mind waiting for conversions etc. I also understand that any sort of compression will reduce quality. To test I converted a 4GB .VOB to a .mp4 using h264 in handbrake and the quality loss was very very very hard to notice.

From what I have understood through research

- Space = .mp4(h.264)
- Quality = .Vob
- Playback = Both equally supported?

But these concerns have yet to be answered:

- My comparison was done on a computer monitor, would the quality loss be substantially noticable if I purchased a 50 inch TV in the future?
- Is this type of file highly supported? (I don't want to experience incompatible players)
- What other issues could a conversion of files such as this cause in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quality loss will be noticeable on larger resolutions. The higher the resolution, the more pixels that the screen attempts to render, thus if the resolution is too high for the media you are playing on it, you will get pixelation.

> My comparison was done on a computer monitor, would the quality loss be substantially noticable if I purchased a 50 inch TV in the future?

You say you converted to a VOB, so it's probably old media? If so, throwing it on a 1080p 50 inch LCD/plasma/LED will probably see degredation.

> Is this type of file highly supported? (I don't want to experience incompatible players)

As far as support goes, MP4/h.264 is a highly supported (usually mobile) format. It will depend on the hardware that you play the media on. Older players will probably not support the format. Newer computer software media players will have the codecs available for it, but some may not.

> What other issues could a conversion of files such as this cause in the future?

As far as this one goes, it depends on technology trends in the area of video compression. Maybe they'll come out with a newer, better compression method, and MP4/h.264 becomes obsolete. But that goes without saying.

Comment: so either way you are going to get degradation on my futuristic 50 inch TV. So both the .vob and h264 would show quality loss in the same manner or would .vob still come out on top?

Comment: What kind of device are you playing this medium on? DVD player? Computer hooked up to tv?

Comment: Computer, Laptop (hooked to TV and not hooked to TV), and the Wii currently but who knows what other devices I will own down the road

Comment: If in the end, all you're doing is doing a dvd conversion of the file, and currently you aren't seeing any video degredation from either, then it's all preference.